# ¿Cómo agregar elementos a un nested dict. formato json con Python?

Tags: python, json

Estoy buscando modificar mi programa de conversión de divisas, con el fin de que cuando z == 3, el programa pueda acceder al archivo de datos `json` con las conversiones disponibles, y pueda agregar a este archivo elementos nuevos en el lugar correcto del diccionario.

El código es:

```
while True:
    z = int(input("""--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Prefiero:
                1.Ingresar un archivo de converesiones de divisas
                2.Elegir de las conversiones disponibles en el sistema #toma los valores del archivo conversion.json
                3.Añadir opciones de conversión al sistema
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                """))
if z == 3:

    new = input("Nombra la nueva moneda: ")   
    new_data = {} #creo un nuevo diccionario

    with open('conversion.json', 'w+') as file:
        data = json.load(file) #cargo el archivo json
        file.close()
    new_data[new['dolares']] = {0.30}  #agrego valores al nuevo diccionario  
    data.update(new_data) #actualizo la información del archivo json con la nueva información
    with open('conversion.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, sort_keys=True) #tiro la actualización de la info al archivo json
        file.close()
```

El archivo json tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    "dolares": [
        {
        "dolares": [1], 
        "euros":  [0.89], #de dólares a euros hay una tasa de conversión de 0.89
        "soles": [3.32], 
        "reales": [3.92], 
        "pesos uruguayos": [33.81], 
        "pesos chilenos": [680.5]
        }
    ], 
    "euros": [
        {
        "dolares": [1.12], 
        "euros": [1], 
        "soles": [3.73], 
        "reales": [4.41], 
        "pesos uruguayos": [37.97], 
        "pesos chilenos": [764.31]
        }
    ],
    "soles": [
        {
        "dolares": [0.30], 
        "euros": [0.27], 
        "soles": [1], 
        "reales": [1.18], 
        "pesos uruguayos": [10.18], 
        "pesos chilenos": [204.97]   
        }
    ]
}
```

el error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Conversion.py", line 65, in <module>
    data = json.load(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Y cuál es el problema que presenta el código?

Comment: data = json.load(file)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Y ese es todo tu código verdad? No estás importante módulos ni nada?

Comment: importo modulo json

Comment: 1) Verifica que el archivo json no esté vacío. 2) Abrelo en modo lectura en vez de escritura. 3) Si todo lo anterior falla, tal vez el archivo JSON contiene como primeros bytes "basura invisible", lo que puede suceder si  l editor con que lo has escrito lo guarda en el formato UTF8+BOM. Mira a ver si puedes guardarlo como UTF8 a secas, o bien elimina las tildes en los comentarios y guárdalo como ASCII

Comment: Por otro lado, si cada divisa tiene asociado un único valor no veo por qué poner ese valor dentro de una lista. Perfectamente puedes poner por ejemplo `"dolares": 1.12,` en vez de `"dolares": [1.12], ` y así con los demás

Answer (score 1):

To problema lo tienes en la manera de abrir tu archivo con el `open` y usando como segundo parámetro `"w+"`. reemplazalo por `"r"` para que sea de solo lectura.

```
...
new_data = {} #creo un nuevo diccionario

with open('conversion.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file) #cargo el archivo json
new_data[new['dolares']] = {0.30}  #agrego valores al nuevo diccionario
...
```

Otra cosa, cuando abres un archivo con `with` no es necesario cerrarlo de manera explicita, ya que `with` lo cierra por ti.

Comment: Cuando usas `"w+"` y haces eso, se borra el contenido de tu archivo. Vuelve a abrir el archivo conversion.json y reescribe tu json.

Comment: Ahora me tira este error .JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: seguramente por que tu archivo conversion.json está vacio, vuelve a escribir el diccionario en el y vuelve a intentarlo.

Comment: Nop, sigue fallando

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de poner new["dolares"], solo debes poner new

Comment: Hola @user211875. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Te invito realizar [tour] para que conozcas cómo funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla. Además, puedes consultar [answer]. Creo que sería una mejor respuesta explicar el porqué de aplicar la solución serviría para evitar el error.